# Importing additional column into sql DB, via c# or sql or?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, excel, datatable

I have a DB with the following fields
Product | Asset | Serial | etc..
these fields were imported from an excel sheet.
I now have the requirement to import an additional field to the DB from the excel sheet, it took me hours to format the sheet in the first place and i dont fancy doing that again.

theres an additional field named productnumber.

say i just import all the excel data messily into another table on my sql db

what sort of function/query/anything can i do for say

```
foreach( item in table1) {
    if(item.serial = table2.serial) {
        item.productnumber = table2.productnumber 
    }
}
```

im seeing datatables in my head, but im not sure how i will make each row check an entire table before moving on?

Thanks guys

EDIT:
ok so i now have two tables

table1 and table 2

table 1
ID | Name | Serial No | Tag | AssetNo | etc...
table 2
Serial No | Tag | AssetNo

I now need to copy all the data from table2.tag to table1.tag and match on assetNo

Thanks

Comment: didn't get your question, you want to import data to a column or add new column to your table in database?

Comment: add a column from excel to an existing DB the serial will be the unique identifier but it is not the primary key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to import the excel sheet directly to the sql server database , then  add a column in your original table and perform  update operation.

Assuming that your original table is `table1` and `serial` is the primary key. 
Import the data from excel into a new table say `table2`. 
Alter `table1` and add the necessary field (`productnumber`).

Perform the following update query

```
update table2 set table2.productnumber =table1.productnumber
from table2 inner join table1 on table2.serial = table1.serial
```